# Number of outcomes in which each pair of defective items is seperated by at least two functional items

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm aware that this "theme" has been asked in different ways on this site, but I'm seeking an explanation to a particular result of this problem.

Here's the prompt:

We have a set of $n$ antennas, of which $m$ are are defective and the remaining $n-m$ are functional. The objective is to determine the number of linear orderings in which no two defectives are next to each other. This particular case makes sense to me. Consider...

Let's denote $x_1$ to as the number of functional items to the left of the first defective, $x_2$ as the number of functional items between the first two defectives, and so on. Schematically,

$x_1 0 x_20...x_m0x_{m+1}$

(Given $0$ represents a defective antenna).

Now, there will be at least one functional item between any pair of defectives as long as $x_i > 0$, $i = 2,...,m$. Hence, the number of outcomes satisfying the condition is the number of vectors $x_1,...x_{m+1}$ that satisfy the equation

$x_1+...+x_{m+1} = n-m$, $x_1\ge0$, $x_{m+1} \ge 0$, $x_i > 0$, $i=2,...,m$

On letting $y_1 = x_1 +1$, $y_i = x_i$, $i = 2,...,m$, $y_{m+1} = x_{x+1} + 1$, we see that this number is equal to the number of positive vectors $(y_1,...,y_{m+1})$ that satisfy the equation

$y_1 + y_2 +...+ y_{m+1} = n - m +2$

Thus, there are ${n -m + 1} \choose m$ such outcomes.

This makes sense to me.

However, there is something I'm missing when I consider this variation: "Suppose now that we are interested in the number of outcomes in which each pair of defective items is separated by at least 2 functional antennas." By the same reasoning, this would equal the number of vectors satisfying the equation

$x_1+...+x_{m+1} = n-m$, $x_1\ge0$, $x_{m+1} \ge 0$, $x_i \ge 2$, $i=2,...,m$

Upon letting $y_1 = x_1 +1$, $y_i = x_i - 1$, $i = 2,...,m$, $y_{m+1} = x_{x+1} + 1$, we see that this is the same as the number of positive solutions of the equation

$y_1 + y_2 +...+ y_{m+1} = n - 2m +3$

Hence, there are ${n-2m+2} \choose m$ such outcomes.

Specifically, I'm having difficulty seeing how the substitution with $y$ in this scenario evaluates to $n-2m+3$. In the first case, it was obviously the result of the two corner cases of $x_1$ and $x_{m+1}$.

There is probably a very simple explanation that is eluding me at the moment. Any constructive input is appreciated.

**Edit**

Note that there is a visual interpretation of the first case of this problem.

Let $1=functional$, and ^ = a place for at most one defective

^ 1 ^ 1 ^ 1...^ 1 ^ 1 ^

Hence, it is clear that there are ${n-m+1} \choose m$ possible orderings. (The 1 arising from the fact that there are $n-m$ functional antennas, and there is an "extra space" at the end of the list if reading from left to right). But I don't see how

^ 11 ^ 11 ^ 11...11 ^ 11 ^

translates into ${n-2m+2} \choose m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with $$x_1+(x_2+ \cdots +x_m)+x_{m+1}=n-m.\tag{1}$$
Then in defining your $y_k$ you are adding $1$ to the terms not in parens, while subtracting $1$ from the $m-1$ terms inside the parens. So the net effect is $1+1+(m-1)\cdot(-1)$ or $-m+3$ being added to the left of $(1).$ So that is also added to the right, giving $n-m+(-m+3)=n-2m+3.$

Comment: It's not clear to me why I can multiply $(m-1)$ by $(-1)$. The rest of the explanation makes sense to me.

Comment: Could the right side also be $n+1$?

Comment: @Mlagma: You are subtracting $1$ from each of the inner $m-1$ terms from $x_2$ up to $x_m$. If one subtracts $1$ a given number of times it's the same as adding $-1$ that many times. So the inner subtraction gives $(m-1)\cdot(-1)$. Try it on a low numbered case. The right side should not be $n+1$.

Comment: Ah, I understand that. I can't say I thought of it in that way. It's a very simple concept, but it slipped by me. I failed to realize that $(m-1)$ was enumerating the number of terms in the parentheses...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am still confused about this question.

Assuming that n-m is talking about the functional and that the +1 is supposed to be the open space where the functional space will be placed, how would the second part even work?

For reference, I understand that m-1 would represent the pairs of defectives, with 2(m-1) talking about the amount of functional needed for the defectives. If we, for example sub in the 2(m-1) for m within the n-m, it would lead to, n-2m+2, but that doesn't make much sense to me for the following reasons.

n-m already represents the functional, so technically, doesn't n-2(m-1) represent the defective pairs? Like n (number of items) minus the total amount of functional needed for defective pairs = defective pairs. Then, by the same logic, shouldn't the m be replaced by m-1 instead, which would make a little more sense since we are saying now: n (number of items) - (m-1) (number of defective pairs) = functional needed. And then we add the +1 for empty spaces (since we are trying to be between each defective). But that would lead to the answer: n-m+2.

Another method was just adding the n-m with 2(m-1), but that would be wrong as well, since I would be left with n-3m+2.

I am very lost.